# Change cell colour based on another cell containing text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am new to Google Sheets and trying to create a custom formula in conditional formatting. Looking to see if someone would be kind enough to help.

The picture below is a sample size of two list of Serial numbers. What I need is the cells to change color if a match is detected. What I was doing before was putting both list under one column and using the formula =countif(B:B,B1)>1. But this formula no longer works for me because now my list have cells that contain more than 1 serial number.
[image]
So what I need help with making a formula that would change the color of the cells if anything in C column is found in the B column. But for cells with more than one serial number, the cell in Column B  would only change once all serial numbers on the cell were matched.  I'm basically trying to verify that all Serial numbers on column C are in column B. But i dont know how to go about it or cells with more than one S/N.

This sounds like a super complicated task. I dont know if i should be asking here. If im at the wrong place please point me where to go

Answer (score 0):

use find insteand of countif

> =find(B1,B:B)>1

Find returns how many times it finds a string in the text or cell value